# Como separar por vírgula os termos de uma string no python?

Tags: python, lista, input

Tenho o seguinte código que lê o nome e a idade de uma pessoa:

```
pessoas = []

p = [str(input('Digite o nome e a idade da pessoa no formato: "Nome 23": '))]
pessoas.append(p)

print(pessoas)
```

Supondo que eu digitei: `"Marcelo 27"`, então `pessoas = [['Marcelo 27']]`.

como faço para pessoas ser igual a `[['Marcelo', 27]]`?

Comment: Nessa época eu estava iniciando meus estudos em python, hoje em dia eu não estudo mais então não lembro muita coisa, mas com base no pouco que lembro e analisando o código, eu vejo que nesse caso faria muito mais sentido ter dois inputs separados para o nome e a idade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp). Um exemplo:

```
>>> "Marcelo 27".split()
['Marcelo', '27']
```

Mas veja que se o nome for duplo, como `Marcos Vinicius`, não vai funcionar como você espera, pois vai retornar `['Marcos', 'Vinicius, '27']`. Aí eu sugiro que faça duas chamadas de `input`.